# Steganography in Doom 2016

Tags: steganography

For the last couple of weeks i'v been trying to replicate the method in which Id Technologies used to hide hidden messages inside their own songs. For reference: https://youtu.be/yzFit0nldf4 .

I'm not sure if this was made by solely a software or a very smart use of heavy musical instruments, but that's what im trying to find out.

Using softwares like coagula might do a similar thing, but the brilliancy was how the coded sound was hidden. If you attempt to hear rendedered output it would sound obvious and aweful...

So, my question is: does anyone know how they did it?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear

Comment: https://sound.stackexchange.com